# subdivision surface may be my issue?

Tags: modeling

I am making Rubik cube pieces. I think my issue is the subdivision modifier. It is causing these weird lines that are going up and down. The model on the left (called corner piece) is a flat surface with the same image texture as the model on the right (called edge piece) is being displayed around a curve. Is the curve causing the issue? How can I fix the problem and still keep the displacement look that added depth to the hex design into the pieces. I have a feeling my issue is from using the displacement and the subdivision modifier together.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you need displacement? Wouldn't a Bump map work well here?

Comment: https://ibb.co/tC1Pznm this is what it looks like from this angle. Now, I tried the bump before, but I can't get the indention of the hex design. I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. Here is what it looks like with the bump added, https://ibb.co/RH7dmw0

Comment: The render-triangulation is clashing with your existing faces. For a start, I think you need some horizontal loops.. But I really think Bump should be enough, here Maybe you could share a cut-down Blend-file on https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes, your node setup for the bump map is wrong. Bump map images are b/w images. Black means pits and white means rises, and grey (#808080) is flat. Set *Colorspace* to *Non-Color* and plug the *ImageTexture* output into the *Height* slot of the *Bump* node. If you want to use additionally a normal map then you need to combine them like shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rXW8.jpg